# Python - update xml value between 2 nodes with regex - re.sub not working

Tags: python, regex, xml

I want to change value between 2 xml nodes - SET_STATUS
filedata is the text that this xml row exist in.

```
<ws:genericAction>SET_STATUS</ws:genericAction>
```

For that wrote the regex :

```
re.sub(r'<\/ws:genericAction>\s*(.*)(?=\n<\/ws:genericAction>)', "New Text", filedata, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

all the program :

```
with open("createUser.txt", 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()
re.sub(r'<\/ws:genericAction>\s*(.*)(?=\n<\/ws:genericAction>)', "New Text", filedata, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
with open("createUser.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use a parser, e.g. `lxml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub()` doesn't modify a string *in place*, it returns the string after replacement:

```
filedata = re.sub(r'(<ws:genericAction>)([^<>]+)(?=<\/ws:genericAction>)', "\\1New Text", filedata, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: Thanks, Now after doing that all my row vanished with "New Text", is there a way to provide regex that will replace only the text between the tags ? <ws:genericAction>SET_STATUS</ws:genericAction>

Comment: @Start, it should become `<ws:genericAction>New text</ws:genericAction>`, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Start, ok, to replace simple text between tags `<ws:genericAction>` - use my update. But using xml parsers is much better for manipulating xml documents

Comment: @Start, in my answer. Check it

Answer (score 0):

A solution with a parser:

```
from lxml import etree

# our test string
xml = '''<root xmlns:ws="http://example.com">
            <ws:genericAction>SET_STATUS</ws:genericAction>
        </root>'''

# the dom
root = etree.fromstring(xml)

# our item(s) as an xpath expression
item = root.xpath(".//ws:genericAction[text()='SET_STATUS']", namespaces = {'ws': 'http://example.com'})

# modify the first one
item[0].text = "Something new here"

# print the new dom
etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

This yields

```
b'<root xmlns:ws="http://example.com">
      <ws:genericAction>Something new here</ws:genericAction>
  </root>'
```

Comment: The problem with this solving is that if I want to give it another parameter after first iteration it will not be found, this is because he looks only for [text()='SET_STATUS'] , this is the reason regex to the wrapping text is more efficient.

Comment: @Start: I doubt that a regular expression alone is "more efficient". You may very well use a regular expression in *combination* with `lxml`.